# CSS3 Rounded Box and Shadow Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following is my part of html code...

**Html Code:**

```
<div class="fotter" >
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Copyright&copy;2012                        
<span style=" float:right;">
<strong>Privacy Policy</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;                
<strong>Contact Us</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;                
<strong>Edumemn</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span>
</div>
```

and

**CSS Code:**

```
.fotter{
padding:10px 0 5px 0;
margin:0 auto; margin-bottom:10px;
background-image:url(../img/fotter.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
height:30px; width:1037px;
border:0;
outline:0;
float:left; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px;   
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 2px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 2px #000;
}
```

and this is my website link..http://nerflek.net/PSD TO HTML/

My questions is.. In Firefox It's show rounded box with shadow in footer part. BUT in Internet Explorer 8 It's Doesn't show any shadow or rounded box.

Is there any one help me about this.
Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: IE8 is old and doesn't support it. I wouldn't put too much time in fixing it. Make it look 'good enough' on Ie8 and wait until everyone has upgraded.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that [border-radius isn't supported by IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius).

For this old browser a "solution" is to use images for corners or, more reasonably, to let the users who don't upgrade have square corners.

Comment: css3pie will give a lot of side effects, be aware

Answer (score 0):

Border -radius is not supported by IE8 , a way around is it to use plugins ,
This one is simple and effective,
http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: there is another light weight plugin you may consider   http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to have a target css for ie.

you can add it like

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normal.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" /> <![endif]-->
</head>
```

In your ie.css you can add background as an image.

ie.css

```
div#samepagecontainer {
..
..
background : #aaa url(/path/to/image.file) no-repeat top left;
..
}
```